# Do A-listers audition for roles?

Tags: production, casting

It is normal for new actors who haven't proven themselves to audition for roles in movies. But What about A-listers like Tom Cruise, Brad Pitt, etc. Do these guys still attend auditions or are scripts just handed to them because they already have the image that fits the character in the movie?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometimes they have to give an audition and sometimes they don't have to give an audition.

If you count Russell Crowe as A-lister then he also gave an audition for the film version of the musical Les Miserables. (Source: [www.dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2035354/Crooner-Crowe-proves-hes-biz-Les-Mis--Russell-gives-incredible-singing-audition-musical-adaptation.html?ito=feeds-newsxml)). There are many other examples over the internet. Even sometimes non-A-listers can also clear auditions over A-listers but an A-lister may get more attention in auditions.

[Scarlett Johansson Auditioned for Les Miserables With Laryngitis & Lost to Anne Hathaway](http://okmagazine.com/get-scoop/scarlett-johansson-auditioned-les-miserables-laryngitis-lost-anne-hathaway/). For this case it looks like one A-lister lost the role to another A-lister.

I'm not sure about Hollywood but in Bollywood sometimes movies are made for an A-lister, so in that case they don't need to give an audition.

Comment: Well, on the other hand *Les Miserables* might also be considered a special case, since the actors' singing abilities might not have been as well-known as their mere acting abilities.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I was going to say the same thing, that is a special part. But if it were an action movie, I doubt Russel Crowe would have needed to audition. But who knows if that guy can even whistle a tune, let alone sing well.

Comment: Russell Crowe is an A-lister in my book. :D

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i have some rumored cases in my mind, which suits better but they are un-sourced rumor. So its better to use les miserable cases, which might be special case but still in-topic and shows a bit of insight.

Comment: @DustinDavis Hah, contrary to common opinion I thought *Russel Crowe* was amazing, love that voice.

Comment: Harrison Ford, when he was cast in the original Star Wars, is a good example of a (then) non-A-lister who got cast without doing an audition over A-listers who actually auditioned (Kurt Russel). He got the part because he was helping other actors read their lines for their auditions and Lucas liked the way he read his part.

Comment: There are youtube videos of Kurt Russel auditioning for Han Solo and videos of Ford helping Carrie Fisher with her audition. Wikipedia includes the casting story in Harrison Ford's bio: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Ford. Wikipedia cites "Empire of Dreams: The Story of the Star Wars Triology" documentary

Comment: I just realized that I knew about it because I watched Empire of Dreams a long time ago on TV. Didn't know it was called "Empire of Dreams" until I googled it a few minutes ago thanks to Wikipedia. Ford's page on Wikipedia is very interesting.

Answer (score 22):

It appears to depend on the film's creators and what *they* want. [E-Online](http://uk.eonline.com/news/81499/do-big-stars-have-to-audition-for-movies) were asked about this via Twitter and published an article as a response, which included this snippet:

> Most of the time, A-list gods and goddesses don't have to read for
>   anything. In fact, even B-plus talent often joins a project before a
>   casting director is even hired.

They concluded their article with this information:

> And that's what happens with many famous actors: a meeting, usually a
>   lunch, where the director or producers can size up an actor without
>   making the talent feel like they're under evaluation [is all that is needed].

Now obviously, E is just a single source of information, but given their role as one of the leading media providers of celebrity news their articles should carry weight on the issue.

An interesting example of this comes from [this article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/30/jake-gyllenhaal-lord-of-the-rings_n_4178546.html), which discusses how an at-the-time fairly unknown Jake Gyllenhaal "bombed" his audition for the [Lord of the Rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_%28film_series%29) trilogy (to play Frodo). The article states:

> Gyllenhaal isn't the only major actor who was discussed as a
>   possibility for Jackson's blockbuster trilogy. Daniel Day-Lewis was
>   one of the first actors that Jackson sought to play Aragorn, but
>   Day-Lewis passed on the opportunity. Russell Crowe was also offered
>   the role of Aragorn, but he passed as well.
>
> In perhaps the most famous bit of "Lord of the Rings" almost-casting,
>   Sean Connery was chosen for the part of Gandalf. "I never understood
>   it. I read the book. I read the script. I saw the movie. I still don't
>   understand it," Connery said about why he decided against starring in
>   "Lord of the Rings."

This seems to suggest that all three of these A-List celebrities were offered roles in the movie after *reading the script*, but not after *auditions*. Clearly, they had the reputation to warrant immediate casting, whereas Gyllenhaal (who at the time was much less known) didn't.

Some actors don't get roles, despite expecting them, because they *refuse* to audition. For example [Beyonce in The Princess and the Frog](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2500391/Beyonc-refused-audition-Disneys-Princess-And-The-Frog--Alicia-Keys-tried-THREE-times.html).

Finally, there are times that famous celebrities are offered roles in films that were in effect created *especially* for them. In these situations, it seems unlikely they would need to audition, as it's the strength of their *previous* work that has attracted the attention of the film's creators.

**Edit:**

As a final, final note, [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Gravity-You-Didn-t-See-Starring-Natalie-Portman-Robert-Downey-Jr-Many-More-39670.html) is an interesting read. It basically tracks the chronological order in which the movie [Gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_%28film%29) approached people for the various roles on offer, before finally setting on George Clooney and Sandra Bullock as lead stars.

Comment: 17 min late......didn't expected that from you :p

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Am I THAT bad at answering immediately?! I was trying not to just reference stuff lol! Trying to put some more of me into it :P

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu: You're very welcome. That was a great question.

Comment: Yes, I +1'd both your answer and your comment.  ;o)

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Ha! That made me laugh :)

Comment: Really tough choosing one of those answers as the accepted answer.The reason i choose Ankit's was because of the first sentence.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu: I appreciate your comment. Whichever answer you feel helps you best if the one you should choose. Users can upvote whichever they want, but ultimately, it's your question - and you chose the answer you preferred. That's the whole point of the site :)

Answer (score 14):

The other two answers here are pretty solid, but I wanted to touch on the sort of "cliques" that exist in Hollywood as well.

Take many of the [Judd Apatow](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0031976/) movies for example. There is an established group of cast members from movie to movie. You get the sense that the roles they play may not necessarily designed for them, but that the genre of movie is so niche that every character is the one they were *"born to play"*. For example, [James Franco](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0290556/?ref_=tt_ov_st) and [Seth Rogan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0736622/?ref_=tt_ov_wr) are often portrayed as the carefree stoner types. This, to me, is the result of actors with established characters, mixing with a group of people whose movies revolve around subjects pertinent to those characters.

[Adam Sandler's films](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001191/#producer) also do this, where a role may not be designed for someone, but rather that person is just part of the group and they are slotted in where they fit the best. [Dan Patrick](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0665830/?ref_=nv_sr_1) and [Dave Matthews](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0559986/?ref_=nv_sr_1) have cameo appearances in several of Adam Sandler's movies and actors such as [Rob Schneider](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001705/?ref_=tt_ov_st) and [Peter Dante](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0200601/?ref_=tt_cl_t13) are always finding themselves with a part.

[Tim Burton](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000318/?ref_=tt_ov_wr) also has several films that feature his wife [Helena Bonham Carter](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000307/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) and [Johnny Depp](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000136/?ref_=tt_ov_st).

Now, these aren't all "A-list" celebrities, but it does go to show other factors in casting that don't revolve around auditions or specific role creation.

Comment: +1: I think you're referring to the idea of being [typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typecasting_(acting)). This definitely is a factor in auditions (look at, for example, Will Ferrell's movies and all the different actors who keep popping up in them).

Comment: @AndrewMartin Yes, although not *just* typecasting. I feel the Johnny Depp roles are definitely typecasting, where he is playing some sort of "creepy" character, but Seth Rogan is more a product of "Who you know, not what you know." I don't mean that to detract from his acting abilities, I just mean that his relationship with Judd Apatow affords him roles he doesn't have to earn by auditioning. And, yes, Will Ferrell's movies are great examples as well.

Comment: Just like Depp working with Tim Burton I suppose, or Matt Damon and Ben Affleck working together (at least in the past).

Comment: @AndrewMartin Matt Damon and Ben Affleck is another good one I didn't think of.

Comment: Ben and Matt is more like nepotism. I think another aspect which hasn't been touched on, but alluded to, is that people get *comfortable* working with each other. A director likes working with an actor, actors like working with each other. After a while, this brings chemistry to the screen.

Comment: Joss Whedon is a classic example of someone reusing actors, it was something I've asked about previously http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15771/why-does-joss-whedon-use-the-same-actors-so-frequently

Comment: @Liath That's good example too. Another thing about Joss Whedon's projects is that they tend to fall into that "cult" category, where the fan bases are very passionate and into the series. These actors/actresses are usually cast due to fan familiarity and expectations. It's similar to typecasting, except that it's more by public demand rather than by acting "talent". By talent, I mean that some are typecast due to physical traits or the sound of their voice. [Ben Stein](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0825401/?ref_=tt_cl_t10) is a good example of someone who (cont. below)

Comment: is cast often for his physical appearance and "dry" voice. This is contrast to many of the actors/actresses from Joss Whedon shows that don't really posses any "unique" traits like that, but rather are so familiar to the fan base that the fans will only ever see them as a character with supernatural powers.

Comment: @DrydenLong you need to put that as an answer on my question!